# Codeigniter getting row details through link (foreach)

Tags: php, html, mysql, codeigniter

I've been doing this for almost a month but I cannot figure it out on how to get the "details" of every row in my table. My table in my view is foreach. And post it in another page. By clicking the link named "Details..." on first page.

for example: ive searched in first page and this is the result:

```
column1      column1      column3      column4      column5      column6

name         desc         age          num          add          Details...
name         desc         age          num          add          Details...
```

When i click the first details... it would go to second page and post name, desc, age, num, add into textbox. same as the second details...
Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

here are my codes:

my model model.php - this is my code for search data in my database table

```
public function search_equip() {

    if ($this->input->post('category') == "All")
    {
    $match = $this->input->post('search');
    $array = array('column1' => $match);
    $this->db->like($array);
    $query = $this->db->get('equip');
    return $query->result();
    }
    elseif ($this->input->post('category') == "Appliance")
    {
    $match = $this->input->post('search');
    $array = array('column1' => $match, 'category' => "Appliance");
    $this->db->like($array);
    $query = $this->db->get('equip');
    return $query->result();
    }
    elseif ($this->input->post('category') == "Furniture")
    {
    $match = $this->input->post('search');
    $array = array('column1' => $match, 'category' => "Furniture");
    $this->db->like($array);
    $query = $this->db->get('equip');
    return $query->result();
    }
    elseif ($this->input->post('category') == "Equipment")
    {
    $match = $this->input->post('search');
    $array = array('column1' => $match, 'category' => "Equipment");
    $this->db->like($array);
    $query = $this->db->get('equip');
    return $query->result();
    }
}
```

my controller search.php - my code with set rules

```
function search_equipment()
{

    //If searchbox is empty    
    $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));

    $this->load->library('form_validation');

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('search', 'Search', 'required|xss_clean');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
        {
        $this->load->view('auth/index', 'refresh'); 
        }
    else
    {
    $data['query'] = $this->model->search_equip();
    $this->load->view('auth/search_view_equipment', $data); 
    }
}
```

my view search_view_equipment.php - this is where i search data and show results with the link every row

```
<?php foreach($query as $item):?>

echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>".<?= $item->Column1 ?>."</td>";
echo "<td>".<?= $item->Column2 ?>."</td>";
echo "<td>".<?= $item->Column3 ?>."</td>";
echo "<td>".<?= $item->Column4 ?>."</td>";
echo "<td>".<?= $item->Column5 ?>."</td>";
echo "<td>".anchor("auth/view_equipment_details/".$item->Column6, 'Details...', array('class' => 'detail'))."</td>";
echo "</tr>";
<?php endforeach;?>
```

my second view view_equipment.php - this is where to post the data coming from first page (specific row)
Note: This td's are input, i dunno how to make a code here using input :)

```
<?php foreach($equipid as $item):?>

echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>".<?= $item->Column1 ?>."</td>";
echo "<td>".<?= $item->Column2 ?>."</td>";
echo "<td>".<?= $item->Column3 ?>."</td>";
echo "<td>".<?= $item->Column4 ?>."</td>";
echo "<td>".<?= $item->Column5 ?>."</td>";
echo "<td>".anchor("auth/view_equipment_details/".$item->Column6, 'Details...', array('class' => 'detail'))."</td>";
echo "</tr>";
<?php endforeach;?>
```

Is it possible to get that whole data of that row and show it in another page? Specifically, I'm confused on what am I going to do, because the table is in foreach. I cannot get the value of the specific link in first page, here's my code on getting the value of links in first page but im not succesful:

controller: auth.php

```
function view_equipment_details()
{
    $data['equipid'] = $this->model->get_equipment_id();
    $this->load->view('auth/view_equipment', $data); 
}
```

model: addition in model.php

```
public function get_equipment_id() {

    $match = $this->input->post(); //This line is where i want to put the specific links ( any links that i click in first page) VALUE or NAME or whatsoever that is EXACTLY THE SAME AS THE ID OF THAT ROW I WILL CLICK to search using (next line): all i need is the value equal to the id of a row in table in database.
    $array = array('id' => $match);
    $this->db->where($array);
    $equipid = $this->db->get('equip');
    return $equipid->result();

}
```

Thank you in advance for any help. Hoping for a feed back. :)

Comment: What i got from your question is you want to get the details of that specific rows on Details click.So you need to attach row id to your detail link like wise you can see the details on another page to that specific row.

Comment: @Zeeshan, yes your right. Thats what I want to do, but with no success ATM. I just want to click that details and get to the other page with that specific row detail.

Comment: Yes thats what i suggested you pass the row id to another page and fetch details of that id from database and show that.if you still have doubts let me know.

Comment: Yes i want to pass that row id in search controller and process it and then go to second page with the specific details of that row. I dont know what to put here $match = $this->input->post(); at the model.php. When ever i change the $match to 'any number that exist in database table' here  $array = array('id' => $match); i got a details of that row in second page. What i intend to do is to get automatically the id number of the row through Details... But i dont know how because the results in first page is in foreach.

Comment: No need for POST here you can just access it as parameter.Check my below answer on how to access the parameter for processing requests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Thanks for your answers guys special.

My Model:

```
public function get_equipment_id($id) {

$array = array('id' => $id);
$this->db->where($array);
$equipid = $this->db->get('equip');
return $equipid->result();

}
```

My Controller:

```
function view_equipment_details($id)
{
$data['equipid'] = $this->model->get_equipment_id($id);
$this->load->view('auth/view_equipment', $data); 
}
```

My View:

```
echo "<td>".anchor("auth/view_equipment_details/".$item->id, 'Details...', array('class' => 'detail'))."</td>";
```

Answer (score 3):

What a mess here budy ...

Your question is really confuse, but I think you are trying to make a link:

```
<?php echo anchor("auth/view_equipment_details/".$item->id, 'Details...', array('class' => 'detail')))?>
```

NOTE: its better to pass an id in the url (or a slug maybe), but not a field, Because you have to do a search in the requested controller using that id.

and then in AuthController the function called view_equipment_details:

```
public function view_equipment_details($id){

   $this->data['equipment'] = $this->db->where('id', $id)->get('table_name')->row();

   $this->load->view(auth/view_equipment', $this->data)
```

}

You are trying to get something from post, and thereś nothing to do with post. The id should come as a parameter.

Comment: Plus one for having the courage to read through OP and actually attempt an answer.  Well done.

Comment: @Patricio thanks for the reply, yeah my codes are all messed up haha. I tried your answer but it does not work. No details are showing in second page.

Answer (score 0):

This way you can access your individual row details on another page.

For example you have page1 with table listing all the rows and a link as you shown for listing details in another page.

So attach ID to your details column within your url,so as per your code it goes like this

```
echo "<td>".anchor("auth/search_details/".$id_of_row, 'Details...', array('class' => 'detail'))."</td>";
```

Now in your controller function named 'search_details' will go like this :

```
function search_details ($row_id)
{
  //code here to get/fetch row from database using $row_id
}
```

This way you can pass specific row details to another page.

Let me know if you any doubts further.

Comment: I already attached every row id in my link here echo "<td>".anchor("auth/view_equipment_details/".$item->Column6, 'Details...', array('class' => 'detail'))."</td>"; But i dont know what will be my controller function. Means i dont know what to put on search_details ($row_id) :/

Comment: Thats what i showed you.Now that you made your function accept parameter the $row_id will be passed to your controller and you can access it within function.

For example to pass $row_id to your model for fetching row would be :
`$this->search_model->get_row($row_id)`

Comment: I did your two codes. But what will i place inside function search_details. Should i put my previous code? $data['equipid'] = $this->model->get_equipment_id();
    $this->load->view('auth/view_equipment', $data); and also what will i put in my model?

Comment: Yes just pass the $row_id you got as parameter in controller to your model where you will get specific row with row_id from db.I guess you should try out the things and if you get any error let me know.

Comment: it does not work, i got an error my LINK IS echo "<td>".anchor("auth/view_equipment_details/".$item->Column6, 'Details...', array('class' => 'detail'))."</td>"; AND MY CONTROLLER IS $data['equipid'] = $this->model->get_equipment_id();
    $this->load->view('auth/view_equipment', $data); AND MY MODEL IS $match = $this->input->post();
  $array = array('id' => $match);
  $this->db->where($array);
   $equipid = $this->db->get('ict');
   return $equipid->result(); BUT I GOT AN ERROR ON LINE $match = $this->input->post(); IN MY MODEL

Comment: I guess you are not following my instructions as i told at first it is not required to use $this->input->post().Alternatively to help you further paste your code to pastebin and give me link to check and update it.